# Azure devops Pipeline: List of Azure Region Locations as Parameter

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I need to create Azure resources. ALL Region/ Location like eastus, westus etc..  should be displayed as Parameter in Pipeline so user can Select any one location for creating the Azure resource using Azure Devops Pipeline. Any suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

Are you using yaml to define your pipeline? If so this is possible using runtime parameters. You essentially define a list of values that can be selected on pipeline running, and if a user doesn't it chooses a default value.

[Runtime Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script)

Comment: can region list be read from some API or some JSON file?

Comment: If your doing it this way you would have to manually add every region as a value